# Saving Selenium Screenshots on Server

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a python code that is using Selenium to take some screenshots.
The screenshots are now stored in the same location as the script, but I want them to be saved directly onto server. (The VM were I'll store the script has access via SSH to that server).
Any ideas are welcome ! Thanks !

Comment: you can create shared folder between to VM's/servers and copy to that

Answer (score 1):

Try using scp remote to local

```
scp -r user@your.server.example.com:/path/to/foo /home/user/Desktop/
```

For local to remote

```
scp -r /home/user/Desktop/ user@your.server.example.com:/path/to/foo
```

Make a folder which saves screenshot in a folder and transfer that folder using scp cmd give above you can also execute this script in the program itself

**Hope it helps**